# Magento 2: add decimal number in the price

Tags: magento-2.0

I am using magento 2.4 and have all the products prices in this format:

```
9.50 ,  67.00 , 50.99
```

How to add another decimal number to become:

```
9.500 ,  67.000 , 50.990
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento 1.9.2.4 or below versions**

Here you can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to add that zero by:

```
    $price = "1234";
    $formatedNumber = number_format($price, 3, '.', '');
    echo $formatedNumber;    //Outputs -> 1234.000
```

Or

```
    $number = "105.90";
    echo number_format((float)$number, 3, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.900
```

**Edit**

**In Magento2**, you can get this by
Using this code inside your view file(.phtml)

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(8,2),true,false);
```

This means there can be 8 digits to the left of the decimal point (8-2) and 2 to the right of the decimal point.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Which file where i can override ?

Comment: Where do you want your price to change? And which version of magento you are using, Please state All details in Question for better understanding.

Comment: I edited the question for magento version and I said I want it general format for all products.